# Dockerize docker API program

Tags: docker, docker-api

I have a program that simply pull a docker image through docker API and run it as a container, I can run it smoothly but my question is, can I dockerize this program?

A few issues I come to is:

- how do I attach the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the first container?
- how do I connect it to the internet so it can pull the image?
- how do I bind the port of the running container inside container to the host port?

Lastly, is it a good idea at all to have a structure like this? if not then what's the alternative?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please limit your question to 1. It's actually one of the close vote reasons. Additionally, you may want to showcase a concrete problem, preferably with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: There are answers to all of these questions (a) in the Docker documentation and (b) here on Stack Overflow.